# Fetching result based on exclusive values: mysql & laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Due to my weak vocabulary, I am not sure If the title of my question is correct but I am trying to explain my need in detail as much I could. Thanks for going through.

I have a table designed to store members of the event. The diagram is below.

```
event_id | user_id
---------|---------------------
1        | 23
1        | 32
3        | 23
3        | 32
3        | 67
```

I want to retrieve `event_id` based on values of `user_id` provided but in a fashion where I want to show only that `event_id` that has given users exclusively.

For example based on an above diagram of the table, If I give user values = (23, 32) only then I should retrieve only event 1, not both 1 and 3 even though event 3 also has above users. I am trying to retrieve events exclusive to given users only.

Here is my laravel implementation:

```
DB::table('events_users')->whereIn('user_id', [23, 32])
                         ->get();
```

This fetches all events that have above users but I want the only event with id 1 based on the above diagram. My current solution is to write another layer of code after fetching where I match the count of users in every event from the query result with the required count. For example, If I am searching only 2 users exclusive event then I will filter out the events from result based on how many total users are in the event. Sorry for my weak vocabulary but I am trying my best to explain.

Is there a way to achieve what I want with a single query?

Comment: You want a pure RAW SQL query ? Or, a Laravel based solution ?

Comment: laravel based. But If you have raw query solution then I think I can try to implement that raw query into laravel solution myself. Thank you.

Comment: as I understand you want know what is the common (same) event between user with these ids:23 & 32. Am I right?

Comment: No, I want event where only members are 23 and 32. because Both event 1 and 3 are shared by both users but in event 3 there is other member present too hence not exclusive event for 23 and 32.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the following solution is also OK:

```
SELECT DISTINCT event_id  FROM events_users GROUP BY event_id 
HAVING GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT user_id ORDER BY user_id asc SEPARATOR ',')="23,32"
```

Your could sort and concat the user_id array to string before the query.

Laravel query builder approach:

```
$user_id_str=implode(",",[23,32]);
DB::table('events_users')
    ->selectRaw("distinct event_id")
    ->groupBy('event_id')
    ->havingRaw("GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT user_id ORDER BY user_id asc SEPARATOR ',')='$user_id_str'")->get();
```

Comment: Have you had issue for scenario where order of input is non-ordered? If I don't order the input beforehand. For example If i search with (32,23) instead of (23,32) i do not get result. I think this is because we are comparing strings in the end and those strings are concatenated version of input values in given order.

For now I am making sure to sort input beforehand asc or desc before sending it to query. So it works there. But I was just curious. Is there alternative where it works for any kind of order?. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One SQL approach would be to use conditional aggregation based filtering. We aggregate on event using `GROUP BY` and then filter out the rows using `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT event_id 
FROM events_users 
GROUP BY event_id 
HAVING 
  SUM(user_id = 23) -- event exists for user = 23
  AND 
  SUM(user_id = 32) -- event exists for user = 32
  AND 
  NOT SUM(user_id NOT IN (23,32)) -- no other row exists other than user 23 and 32
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: This solution doesn't work for scenario where multiple events are there with same kind of exclusive members. This is incorrect solution. I apologise. 
**Solution from Phil works so I have marked it as solution.**

I have got the solution that worked for me. If you think there is flaw then please let me know.

```
DB::table('events_users')
                    ->whereIn('user_id', [23, 32])
                    ->havingRaw('count(user_id) = ?', [2])
                    ->get();
```

This gives me exclusive events that has users 23 and 32 only, no other members. I have made assumption that given users and count of users are mutually exclusive because there will not be duplicate user entry within an event. let me know if this fails in any scenario.

Comment: Yes, this works. Above code should get you collection not null. If not match is found then it should fetch empty collection but not null afaik.

Comment: Yes, it got the empty collection. But you want get event 1, right?

Comment: Yes. Its returning event 1 for me. It's working on my project. Can you make sure that in your table event 1 has only 2 members that you are searching? In above my code I am searching (23 and 32) and also making sure event has just 2 members.

Comment: Yes. I copied your data in my local environment. And my proposal also works in my local environment.

Comment: Weird. It's working. I tested with my all real data in table with various combination. here is my json response too.

{
    "message": "Event exists.",
    "data": {        
        "event_id": 1,
        "created_at": "2019-09-21 12:00:14",
        "updated_at": "2019-09-21 12:00:14"
    }
}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199768/discussion-between-padam-thapa-and-phil).